# How to find a polynomial time algorithm to find vertices in a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

Can you help me to find the polynomial-time algorithm for the following problem: Let G = (V, E) be a simple undirected graph, and x, y ∈ V; find the shortest simple (no vertices repeated) cycle which contains x and y.

Update:

```
G: undirected graph.

 d__________e
/           \
x--a--b--c---y
 \___/
 t  u
```

If you run floyd warshall algorithm it will stop after finding the cycle from `x a b u t`, but in this problem we need to find the cycle `C` which inclucdes vertics of x and y. So correct cycle is `x d e y c b a` I see this problem can be solved using max-flow, but I am still struggling to find the exact reduction. Hopefully, this helps here.

Comment: What if there is no cycle that contains both x and y?

Comment: @KennyLau - if no cycle means then we don't need to do anything, simple exit from the function.

Comment: Do you know Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: @MichaelBiro - yes  I know, but Dijkstra's algorithm is used find the shortest path, so I am not sure how we can use it here.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358259/finding-shortest-cycles-containing-two-nodes). A google search reveals lots of matches for this question.

Comment: @rogerl Do you distinguish directed and undirected graphs?

Comment: no, it's just undirected simple graph.

Comment: @KennyLau, Update has more explanations.

Comment: @rogerl - Update has more explanations

Comment: @MichaelBiro Update has more explanations

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it feels like I'm doing your homework, and this seems to make some people on this site very nervous. Therefore I will begin by giving some hints. Let me know if you need more help!

---

Hint 1:

> To find a simple cycle containing $x$ and $y$ is to find two vertex-disjoint paths $x \leadsto y$.

Hint 2:

> Reduce the problem to a minimum cost flow problem.

Hint 3:

> The cost is $1$ for each edge; the capacity is $1$ for each *vertex*.

Comment: But min-cost flow doesn't  have polynomial time algorithm, right ?

Comment: say If I reduced this problem to min-cost, i think no use since we don't have any polynomial time algorithm

Comment: thank you for the hints. helped a lot.

Comment: I got the solution finally :)

Comment: @Sam All right, well done! Did you find a polynomial time algorithm for min-cost flow? :-)

Comment: Yes :-) Your hins connected to my lecture notes, finally I got polynomial time algorithm.